# How to corectly Loop over days

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a string with start dates and end dates.   That can loop over X number of days.

```
int nrOfDaysToLoopBy = 3;

List<string> Dates = new List<string>();

string startDate = "2014-01-01";  //this date is given to me by an api I am just hard codeing for testing
string endDate = "2014-01-30";
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime myDate = StartDate;  // setting the initial date

for (DateTime date = StartDate.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy); date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy))
{
    Dates.Add("start-date=" + myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&end-date=" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    myDate = date.AddDays(1); 
}

// Dealing with any left over days.
if (myDate != EndDate && EndDate > myDate)
{
   Dates.Add("start-date=" + myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&end-date=" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

My results:

```
start-date=2014-01-01&end-date=2014-01-04
start-date=2014-01-05&end-date=2014-01-07
```

The problem here is that there is 4 days between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-04 not 3.

Results I am trying to get:

```
start-date=2014-01-01&end-date=2014-01-03
start-date=2014-01-04&end-date=2014-01-06
```

Update:
Can we agree that the days between `2014-01-01&end-date=2014-01-04` are
`2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03, and 2014-01-04`  That's 4

I have been playing with this for a few hours now and nothing I have done has fixed the problem.

Comment: what is the `nrOfDaysToLoopBy` for your "Results I am trying to get"?

Comment: oops sorry forgot that variable I added it.   int nrOfDaysToLoopBy = 3;

Comment: try int nrOfDaysToLoopBy = 2

Comment: I ask my user how many days do you want to loop over if he wants to loop over 3 they I have to say 3.  2 != 3

Comment: What are you asking for?  What does `nrOfDaysToLoopBy` represent?  What is the point of this?

Comment: Consider utilising the TimeSpan type ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is that there is 4 days between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-04 not 3.

One could argue that there's 3 days between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-04: Between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-04, three 24h periods pass:

- 2014-01-01 -- 2014-01-02
- 2014-01-02 -- 2014-01-03
- 2014-01-03 -- 2014-01-04

You see, the problem is how you define *between*. If you want to include the start *and* the end date, you need to adjust the number of dates you add.

Edit:

This fixed the problem.  nrOfDaysToLoopBy-1

```
 for (DateTime date = StartDate.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy-1); date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy))
 {
  }
```

Comment: "you need to adjust nrOfDaysToLoopBy" What adjustment would produce the desired output?

Comment: Can we agree that the days between 2014-01-01&end-date=2014-01-04 are 2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03, and 2014-01-04 That's 4

Comment: @DaImTo: I've updated my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: hmm I see your point but adjust sounds a little like hack to me.  What will happen if the user says they want to loop over 1 day

Comment: @BenAaronson: For didactic reasons, I'd like to leave that as an exercise to the reader. Once you've understood how date math works, it's trivial.

Comment: @DaImTo: How many days to you want to be between 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-01?

Comment: @Heinzi Simply subtracting 1 from the `nrOfDaysToLoopBy` (as suggested in the now deleted other answer) doesn't work for reasons explained in my answer.

Comment: I hadn't used AddDays before, thank you for taking the time to explain how it works.

Comment: @DaImTo Just to be clear, what was your eventual fix for this?

Comment: I edited the answer with the actual solution.  It works with 1 as well.  Which makes sense now that I think of a Date as well 24 hour period of time :)

Comment: @DaImTo Yep, that's right. Just wanted to check you weren't falling into the same trap as the deleted answer!

Comment: I think I had been looking at it for to long.  Once I thought about it I understood what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the statement:

```
DateTime date = StartDate.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy);
```

in your `for` loop initialization to

```
DateTime date = StartDate.AddDays(nrOfDaysToLoopBy-1);
```

The issue is that when you add days, the number of days "between" as you're calling it is actually the number of days you add + 1. So monday->monday (zero days added) is 1 day, monday->tuesday (one day added) is 2 days, etc. That's why you need the -1 modification for the start date.

The reason you don't need this alteration on every other iteration on the loop is because of the `myDate = date.AddDays(1)` line. This *reduces* the difference between `myDate` and `date` by one, bringing it back to the correct difference

Comment: +1 for putting into words what I could only explain by example.